# Can not see crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I can not see crashlytics. I have this in my build.gradle file. Not sure, I've done all the practices as they have stated and copy pasted the exact google-service.json file from the docs when setting up the firebase for my project. Can anyone see why it's not working thanks!

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

My Project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I checked the crashlytics dashboard enabled there in the firebase console. still no crashes could be captured. I"m crashing by using a runtime exception in android

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        throw RuntimeException("Test Crash")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the part with applying the plugin inside project and app level build.gradle.kts (Step 3 in the docs)

`build.gradle.kts(project)`
`classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'`

`build.gradle.kts(app)`
`apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'`

You can do it step-by-step with the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android)

Comment: I've added both the lines it's still not working. can you please provide any other solution?

Comment: Did you do everything just like in the docs I linked? You can also enable debug logging for crashlytics to see if it's sending the reports. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable-debug-logging

Comment: yes it's working fine now.